# Dynamic Table with django form

Tags: python, django, forms

So I've read the docs and looked at a couple of answer but I think I'm confusing myself here.

I'm trying to build a table that can have dynamically added rows to it. My table row is constructed from my form called `ModbusRegistersForm`. The difficulty I'm having here is understanding how this will work with my form since every time a row is added, it's basically another `ModbusRegistersForm` being added(via jquery). What would be an acceptable way of adding these dynamically added fields to my form? Since each row is pretty much a duplicate of `ModbusRegistersForm`, should they all be added to a list inside `ModbusRegistersForm`? or is there a specific way to go about this? I'm currently looking at formsets but from the docs it seems (to me at least) like you'd have to pre-define the amount of `extra` forms you want so it won't work since it's dynamic.

```
class ModbusRegistersForm(forms.Form):
    OPTIONS = (('1', '(01) Discrete Output Coils'),
               ('2', '(02) Discrete Input Contacts'),
               ('3', '(03) Analog Output Registers'),
               ('4', '(04) Analog Input Registers')
               )

    starting_address = forms.IntegerField(max_value=99999,
                                          widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                                    'placeholder': 'Starting address',
                                                    'class': 'form-control'
                                              }))
    ending_address = forms.IntegerField(max_value=99999,
                                          widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                                    'placeholder': 'Ending address',
                                                    'class': 'form-control'
                                              }))
    register_type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={
                                                    'class': 'form-control',
                                                    'id': 'register-type'
                                              }), 
                                               choices=OPTIONS
                                             )
    offset = forms.IntegerField(max_value=9999,
                                required=False,
                                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                        'class': 'form-control',
                                        'placeholder': 'Address offset'
                                    }))

class CreateModbusForm(forms.Form):
    port = forms.IntegerField(label="TCP/IP Port:",
                              max_value=65535,
                              validators = [[RegexValidator(regex='\d{1,5}', message='Not a valid port', code='Invalid port')]],
                              widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                        'placeholder': 'Port',
                                        'class': 'form-control',
                                        'id': 'port',
                                  }))
    slave_id = forms.IntegerField(label="Slave ID:",
                              max_value=247,
                              widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                        'placeholder': 'Slave id',
                                        'class': 'form-control',
                                        'id': 'slave-id',
                                  }))
    ip_address = forms.CharField(label="IP Address",
                         max_length=16,
                         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                'placeholder': 'Modbus IP address',
                                'class': 'form-control',
                                'id': 'ip-address',
                            }))

    device_name = forms.CharField(label="Device Name:", 
                                  max_length=50, 
                                  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                      'placeholder': 'Modbus device name', 
                                      'class': 'form-control', 
                                      'id': 'device-name'
                                      }))
```

views.py

```
    modbus_device = CreateModbusForm()
    registers = ModbusRegistersForm()

    return render(
        request,
        'app/create_modbus.html',
        context_instance = RequestContext(request,
        {
            'title':'Create Modbus Device',
            'tag': 'create_modbus',
            'modbus_device': modbus_device,
            'registers': registers
        })
    )
```

html

```
                                 <tbody>
                                    <tr id='addr_0'>
                                        <td>
                                        1
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            {{ registers.starting_address }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            {{ registers.ending_address }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            {{ registers.register_type }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            {{ registers.offset }}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr id='addr_1'></tr>
                                </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formsets are indeed the answer. You can increment the extra and total forms attributes via Javascript, since they are stored as hidden fields, and you can also use the formset's `empty_form` method to output (eg in a hidden div) an empty form that your JS can clone and update its fields' name/ID attributes.

Comment: Would I have to declare the hidden inputs manually?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. In order to use a formset, you need to output `{{ formset.management_form }}` in the template. That includes those hidden fields, which you can then update via JS.

Comment: ah, then I must be utilizing it wrong, the code I have for my table is posted in my question hence why I was asking because I didn't see any formset hidden fields.